# Angular material input

Tags: angular

Can any one help me in angular material that I am using a mat form filed when it's invalid it's outline getting red but I need only left side border will be red with some solid 4px when I try this it won't woking..Any suggestions

I am sharing pic[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kG10H.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **::ng-deep** selector in your component's styles to target the specific elements you want to modify. Keep in mind that **::ng-deep** is a deprecated method, but currently, there is no direct replacement for it in Angular.

Try this

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-invalid .mat-form-field-outline-end {
  border-left: 4px solid red;
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field-invalid .mat-form-field-outline-gap {
  border-left: 4px solid red;
}

/* Adjust the padding to ensure content doesn't overlap with the border */
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-invalid .mat-form-field-flex {
  padding-left: 4px;
}
```

**::ng-deep** to target the specific elements of the mat form field that control the outline